# How to know the source of EINTR?

Tags: linux

When I run the following code, the EINTR error occurs frequently:

```
fprintf(stderr, "start select\r\n");
    result = select(FD_SETSIZE, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    fprintf(stderr, "select end : %d \r\n", result);

    if (result < 0)
    {
        if (errno != EINTR)
        {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error in select(): %d %s\r\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        }
    }
```

There is no problem with this app running on my Linux server. But when it runs on one of my embedded devices, EINTR constantly appears. There are some other processes on my device performing their own business. So how do I know where EINTR comes from?

Comment: Does this app receives any `signal`s? So why not just don't care and loop it, like `do { errno = 0; result = select(...); } while (result == -1 && errno != EINTR);` ? `of my embedded devices` What is that "device"? Does it run linux? There is also `pselect` that takes `sigset_t`.

Comment: Hi，my device is also a Linux system，I did ignore EINTR, so my functionality wasn't affected.  But the frequency of EINTR is too high, so I want to know which signal and who sent it.

Comment: most likely you aren't resetting tv

Comment: I set the tv.tv_sec/tv.tv_usec value before each call to select